# Terminate process at any step (jbpm)

Tags: jbpm

I'd like to implement the ability to terminate the process instance at any user task of my jbpm project. I know that I should theoretically be able to do this with a termination end event attached to any task in my workflow, but this seems like a bad solution to have so many terminate events.

Is there a better, more efficient, more readable way to do this?

Comment: Were you able to find a better approach to have the process terminate at any step? (or did you use @antmendoza's solution below?)

Comment: We've written some untested front-end functionality to recursively kill all processes with the remote api. So in other words it's been accomplished with a button on our front end that can be clicked at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is better, but you can do this:

- model, in parallel,  a intermediate catch signal followed by your terminate event
- use the space "On Exit Script" on Human Task to notify mentioned signal, using method signalEvent `kcontext.getProcessInstance().signalEvent("terminate",null);` where "terminate" is the signal's name catched by your Signal Event.

Here you can see a approach: http://s7.postimg.org/p6ktmvz0r/Screen_Shot_2015_01_18_at_19_45_48.png

Comment: If you have _n_ tasks, and the process can end in any one these these _n_ tasks, then this solution would involve adding a gateway before these these _n_ tasks to catch the terminate signal event? Are there any other ways to accomplish termination?

Comment: Hi!! @jl987 1) No, it doesn't involve adding a gateway before each task. 2) yes, I'm sure there are other ways... what do you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The app we ended up building used a custom front-end which interfaced with a JBPM service.

To terminate process at any step we recorded the master process instance ID in our own database when it was created. We then created a 'cancel project' function which recursively collected all process ids under a single master process id, and then terminated them via remote API, starting with the master process id.

Note that if you do this, you need to abort the list of process instances starting from the master process, and then work your way forward. If you don't, aborting child processes first can spawn more processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the process to be deleted you can use the following code:

```java
processService.abortProcessInstance(processInstanceId);
```

`processService` is the follow interface: `org.jbpm.services.api.ProcessService`

This will **delete** the **process instance** and the **task** associated with it.

For reference this code used `org.jbpm:jbpm-services-api:7.65.0.Final`

This code was executed from within a spring-boot application that is integrated with JBPM.