# Terminate process instance in jBPM 6

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

There's similar issue at
[Terminate process at any step (jbpm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910474/terminate-process-at-any-step-jbpm)

Similarly, I'd like to implement the ability to terminate the process instance at any task (script task, user task, service task). I can try to add a gateway with an intermediate catch event for each single task in my workflow. But it seems inefficient and makes the bpm diagram cluttered.

In Oracle BPM, it's easy to have a `Message Wait` event and an automatic task where I can do `this.action=ABORT`.

[image: Oracle BPM Terminate]

Similarly in my jBPM process, an user would send a "terminate" command through an UI which would terminate the process. Before termination, however, the process will do some post processing (i.e.,: update db table or send an email to notify users of termination) which I'd like to perform inside a custom work item handler. An example of the workflow would like look this. I know that this doesn't conform to the bpm specification that an user task should have one incoming and one outgoing connection.

[image: Example workflow with termination signal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an signal event sub-process that would listen for some 'terminate' signal and perform the termination script and then terminate the process instance.  You can specify this once as a separate section in your diagram (basically remove the nodes you added and put a new event sub-process at the button with a signal event -> script -> terminate end event instead).

Comment: Thanks Kris for the suggestion.

Comment: Is there any way to send signal via script? then we don't want to set the process variable, then append XOR gateway and throw-signal-node after it.